# Should I up-vote a comment pointing out I was wrong before I delete my answer?

Tags: discussion

So I was wrong. No biggie, but I want to delete my answer to save myself the embarras... I mean, to not confuse other readers! Yes, that's it.

I do appreciate being pointed at my wrong answer, does up-voting the comment that did it contribute in any way to showing my appreciation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should probably just comment to the person who steered you right.

As it stands, up-voting a comment doesn't do anything for the person who commented, and they don't get a notification.
However if you reply to the comment (using `@username`) they will see it.

It can be frustrating to leave comments trying to help people, only to feel ignored.
So if you do this small thing, you're helping out a great deal! You're signaling to someone that they did in fact make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Deleted answers including comments and votes on them will be visible to moderators and users with 10k reputation. But it won't be visible who voted. And if the person who commented cannot see the answer anymore, they may never know that their comment got a positive vote.

But it is still worth upvoting their comment, after all it only takes one click to do so.

Writing a reply using `@username` as pointed out by @Reaces will trigger a notification to that user. So you could write something like: `@username my bad, I'll delete this answer.`

I'm not entirely certain if you then need to wait for them to see the comment before you delete the answer, or if your response remains visible in their notifications, even if the answer it was attached to is long gone.

Comment: Notifications for comments on deleted posts aren't deleted - they persist in the inbox.

Comment: they assuredly do not show in the inbox when deleted anymore. it's been fixed since some weeks, if I recall correctly.